# Dynamic Request path

Tags: laravel-8

I am using `Request::path()`.  It's value will be `integration-detail`.

How can I make it dynamic ?

Like `Request::path() == 'integration-detail/2'`, `Request::path() == 'integration-detail/9'`, `Request::path() == 'integration-detail/5'` etc.

Comment: do u want to catch current url or current url route name ?

Comment: Thanks @RiponUddin. I would like to catch like `Request::path() == 'integration-detail/$id'`.

Answer (score 1):

At web.php

```
Route::get("integration-detail/{id}","Controller@methodName")->name("integrationDetails");
```

At your Blade file or anywhere

```
@php 
   $currentRoute = Route::current()->getName();
@endphp

@if($currentRoute == "integrationDetails")
      // Condition True 
@else
      // Condition false
@endif
```

I hope it will help you.